# Is there a way to override the default animation on UITextField when clicking on it on tvOS

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, tvos, uivisualeffectview

UITextField has a default animation where the background becomes completely white on apple tvOS. I can update the UI when it's focused but when you click on it, it has it's own background animation. I was wondering if there was a way to override this animation. I couldn't find where it's doing it. I am running tvOS 9.2.2. 
The UITextfield is added to : self.navigationItem.titleView

This is what it looks like:

[image: Screen Cap]

When Debugging the view hierarchy, it seems that the UITextField has a UIVisualEffectView set. Is there a way to remove this view ?